# Getting a “Secure Boot Violation” on an MSI Modern 14 after a Windows 11 update failed

Tags: windows, bios, windows-11, secure-boot, windows-11-upgrade

Upgraded Windows 10 to Windows 11 on MSI Modern 14 earlier this year via Update assistant. I saw the latest Windows 11 22H2 update and put the MSI modern 14 to upgrade via Windows 11 Installation Assistant downloaded from Microsoft site:

https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11

During the installation maybe about 80% I forgot about it and shut down the computer. Did something like this before and there was not problem. So I didn't think about it as I was tired and went to sleep.

Opend up the laptop next morning and it shows a message saying "SECURE BOOT VIOLATION" and after I clicked “OK” to that it takes me to the BIOS. Tried changing the boot order but nothing.

The UEFI option is grayed out. Disabling Secure boot does nothing. It directly takes me to BIOS without the error.

My question is, if I make a botable USB drive can I repair the Windows 11 OS without formatting the laptop?

Are there any other solution to this? I would maybe want to backup some documents.

Comment: Please do not edit any question to declare that something is fixed as you did in a [recent edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1743706/revisions). You are free to self-solve questions you have posted [as you have already done](https://superuser.com/a/1746503/167207). Just post the answer and then wait 2 days to to check off your answer as the answer and that’s it! More info on how to self-answer can be found [here](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

During the installation maybe about 80% I forgot about it and shut down the computer.  *<--- You should really take more care to protect yourself.*

> if I make a botable USB drive can I repair the Windows 11 OS without
> formatting the laptop?

Windows has to be running for a Repair Install to work. You cannot boot to a non-running machine and do a repair install.

So boot with a bootable USB Key and recover your data and documents and then reinstall Windows.

Make sure you are using UEFI and then also (UEFI enabled) that Secure Boot is enabled as well. Both of these need to be enabled for Windows 11.

Also get WhyNotWin11 from Github and check the Windows 11 parameters with that.

Comment: I took a backup and reinstalled Windows. But I get the same SECURE BOOT VIOLATION error on my system.

Comment: Is your BIOS UEFI?  That is are you using UEFI?  Is Secure Boot turned ON?  You need UEFI for Secure Boot.

Comment: Yes. It's a pretty new laptop. It has UEFI.

Comment: Make sure you turn on Secure Boot. Also if new enough, ask the manufacturer for support.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone suffering from this nightmare of an update, it's actually MSI's fault. Solution below.

More details on this issue can one found in [this post on the official MSI forum](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/modern-14-windows-11-22h2-update-broke-system.379023/#post-2147633).

The problem is resolved by downgrading the BIOS to 112 and a newer BIOS will be released later to fix the problem [as explained here](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/unable-to-boot-in-system-after-updating-windows-11-sun-valley2.379048/).

So I downgraded the BIOS to 1.1.2 and it booted the operating system!

For the Modern 14 B4MW model, you can download the BIOS [from here](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/Modern-14-B4MW/support?sub_product=Modern-14-B4MW#bios).

And you can also upgrade the BIOS to 115 (E14DKAMS.115) by [downloading it from here](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/Modern-14-B4MW/support?sub_product=Modern-14-B4MW#bios).

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just want to share what I did and I hope this helps you too :D

Make/Model: MSI Laptop Modern 14 B4MW

Error: Secure Boot Violation. Invalid Signature Detected. Please check your Bios Policy Setup

Occured: After Windows 11 Update
22H2 Installation

DO NOT DOWNGRADE YOUR BIOS.

Steps taken:

1. Download the latest BIOS from MSI official page <msi.com> it will be downloaded as a ".zip" file so you need to extract the file
2. Save the extracted files to a flashdrive or external drive
3. Restart/reboot your MSI machine.
   Upon start up, kindly press "Delete" key/button for 5 secs or so til the BIOS Menu appear
4. Press the LEFT "ALT key"+ right " fn + ctrl + shift key" and f2 simultaneously
   the hidden options should appear now.
5. Go to ADVANCED tab
6. Plug your flashdrive/external harddrive where the extracted .zip file with the latest BIOS was saved
7. Click the bottom option which would be Update BIOS
8. Select the respective flash/harddrive folder and click the file
9. Flash Update Bios
10. Restart your device, make sure not to interrupt the update and plug your AC Adapter/ Charger. It should be working afterwards as well as the files should not be corrupted.

- Naddie

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Actually, this is quite a widespread issue, regarding the "Secure boot violation" error message on MSI Modern 14 model. The straightforward solution is to simply downgrade the BIOS version from version .114 to .112 per MSI support. They will also release a new BIOS update, soon, to address this issue.

Read this, for more info and BIOS download link:
https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/unable-to-boot-in-system-after-updating-windows-11-sun-valley2.379048/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Vlad - You should include the downgrade instructions with your answer.

Comment: Hello. To downgrade the BIOS follow the same steps as updating it.